# Win7 becomes unstable after waking from sleep and trying to access esata drive

Tags: windows-7, sleep, esata, wake-up, black-screen-of-death

I have the following problem:

I have a HTPC at home which is only used for its Mediacenter but since recently has an esata storage enclosure to record all its data to. The esata enclosure has a built-in sleep function if there is no activity. This seems to be the cause of my problem.
Whenever the enclosure goes to sleep (and after a while the Mediacenter as well), whenever I wake up the HTPC, WIN7 becomes unstable because the esata enclosure is still awakening (takes about 3 secs and the HTPC less than 1).
So when I awake the PC whilst the enclosure is still active, no problem what so ever! This is how I figured out this is causing the problem.

So what happens when the system becomes unstable, well here are a couple of things that happen every time, and some of you will recognize the issues (maybe now you know the cause):

- the cpu LED will remain constantly on
- after login, it will take ages to get you to the desktop screen (in my case the media center)
- the cd-rom drive will no longer be available (sata)
- List item
- the system can no longer sleep and recover (wake) from it again. This results in a black screen with a blinking cursor.
- a cold reboot is the only way to boot your system again. Using a simple restart will het you the black screen again.

=> so all these issues are caused by the fact that there was a delay in accessing the esata.

How can this be solved. I cannot configure the sleep settings of the esata enclosure, unfortunately.

My system = Win7 ultimate 32-bit on SSD, esata enclosure in Raid5 (Sharkoon 5-bay raid box), sata blu ray drive, Asus P7P55D E PRO,  4gb DDR3, Intel i3 2,98Mhz

PS: this MS Hotfix for larger drives dissapearing, is not solving it. Actually on this case, the drive is not dissapearing.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same enclosure, attached to a Mac OS X computer via a Silicon Image 3132-based PCI card, and have noticed similar (albeit not quite the same) trouble.

It seems to me that with this enclosure it is important to avoid placing high-capacity drives with "intelligent" parking features (e.g. Western Digital EARS) in the 1st (topmost) slot. I've inserted an unformatted 80Gb disk in the first slot, kept the 2Tb green WDs elsewhere and the problem waking from sleep seems to be alleviated.